# GmailApp without Gmail

Tags: google-apps-script

While looking into Google Apps script, I happened to try the very first "sample" script here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview

But running the script caused this error:

> We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again.
>   (line 21, file "Code")

I eventually realized that the particular account I was using is a Google account that isn't linked to a Gmail account. I tried another Google account that is linked to a Gmail account and it worked just fine. So, I'm assuming that's the problem, but the error doesn't exactly indicate that.

I'm hoping someone can confirm that is indeed the problem and whether this is something that should be addressed in the sample code and/or have the error improved (obviously waiting a bit and trying again probably isn't going to fix the issue).

Also, if being linked to a Gmail account is required to use GmailApp, is there any way to send email without being linked to a Gmail account?

*Update:*

Apparently you can use `MailApp.sendEmail()` to send email without being linked to a Gmail account.

I still think the sample script error handling and messaging needs improvement.

Comment: Hello, please take a look at what types of questions to ask [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Are you saying my question is not appropriate? Please help me understand. I asked a non-subjective question about a problem related to programming. My question exactly fits the template of "“I would like others to explain ______ to me” where the "blank" is "why a function call is failing". This site also appears to be the Google-recommended site for programmers having trouble with Google Apps Script. So, while I fully appreciate the concern for keeping questions on target, I truly don't understand the concern here (if that is what your comment is meant to imply).

Comment: im not sure what else you expect to happen? how can it send email if it doesnt have one? what you expect to appear under "to"? etc. or is this just about the cryptic error text?

Comment: The initial issue was trying to understand why the failure happened at all. The error message was totally useless. It recommended "waiting a bit" which obviously would never have helped. I managed to figure out the issue (and I updated the issue appropriately). Sure, it makes sense now, but it was not obvious that was the reason. Seems like 2 things are needed. 1) Fix the error message 2) Since this came from Google's very first sample app, they should advise their sample only works with Google Accounts that have an associated Gmail account. Wouldn't that be more helpful?

Comment: The update to your question was what made it work for me. Thanks for the update.